# Can find example database for music (include stream_uri of music)?

Tags: api, audio-player, audiotrack

Where can i get example database for music (include stream_uri of full audio track), just for example project?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not music - but if you are happy with Podcasts you can access the public PlayerFM API https://player.fm/featured/true-crime.json?episode_detail=full

For purely testing purposes https://storage.googleapis.com/uamp/catalog.json from the https://github.com/android/uamp project.